# Retrieving hashmap values in java

Tags: java, hashmap

I wrote below code to retrieve values in hashmap. But it didnt work.

```
HashMap<String, String> facilities = new HashMap<String, String>();

Iterator i = facilities.entrySet().iterator();

while(i.hasNext())
{
    String key = i.next().toString();  
    String value = i.next().toString();
    System.out.println(key + " " + value);
}
```

I modified the code to include SET class and it worked fine.

```
Set s= facilities.entrySet();
Iterator it = facilities.entrySet().iterator();
while(it.hasNext())
{
    System.out.println(it.next());
}
```

Can anyone guide me what went wrong in above code without SET class??

P.S - I do not have much programming exp and started using java recently

Comment: what error are you getting with the hashmap, i.e what is displayed ?

Comment: What did you expect and what did you experience instead?

Comment: I am not getting any error. But nothing gets displayed in the output screen. So i googled and  used SET class instead. Then it displayed the values. So my question is why didnt it display the value without SET class?

Answer (score 11):

You are calling `next()` two times.

Try this instead:

```
while(i.hasNext())
{
    Entry e = i.next();
    String key = e.getKey();  
    String value = e.getValue();
    System.out.println(key + " " + value);
}
```

In short you could also use the following code (which also keeps the type information). Using `Iterator` is pre-Java-1.5 style somehow.

```
for(Entry<String, String> entry : facilities.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    String value = entry.getValue();
    System.out.println(key + " " + value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you're calling `i.next()` to get the key, then you call it again to get the value (the value of the next entry).

Another problem is you use `toString` on the one of the `Entry`'s, which is not the same as `getKey` or `getValue`.

You need to do something like:

```
Iterator<Entry<String, String>> i = facilities.entrySet().iterator();
...
while (...)
{
   Entry<String, String> entry = i.next();
   String key = entry.getKey();  
   String value = entry.getValue();
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Iterator i = facilities.keySet().iterator();

while(i.hasNext())
{
    String key = i.next().toString();  
    String value = facilities.get(key);
    System.out.println(key + " " + value);
}
```

Comment: This will not result in the best performance. And this code is more difficult to read in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `i.next()` more than once in the loop. I think this is causing the trouble.

You can try this:

```
HashMap<String, String> facilities = new HashMap<String, String>();
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> i = facilities.entrySet().iterator();
Map.Entry<String, String> entry = null;
while (i.hasNext()) {
    entry = i.next();
    String key = entry.getKey();
    String value = entry.getValue();
    System.out.println(key + " " + value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String key;
for(final Iterator iterator = facilities.keySet().iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {<BR>
   key = iterator.next();<BR>
   System.out.println(key + " : " + facilities.get(key));<BR>

for (Entry<String, String> entry : facilities.entrySet()) {<BR>
System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " : " + entry.getValue();<BR>
}
```