# Deleted image appears again in ListView

Tags: android, listview

In my application i add images to listview and transfer those images to servelet after conversion into string. But deleted image from listview also transfer. It removes from listview, but string is transfering to servelet. This is annoying . I am not getting where to add these lines in BaseAdapter.

```
                 Bitmap image=(Bitmap)getItem(position);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
            //encode image
            byte[] b = bytes.toByteArray();
             encodedImageString = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
    //encodedImageString is sent to servlet, it's showing deleted image string also
```

Here is a complete code of BaseAdapter

```
    public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
      ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> imageHashMap=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public MyAdapter() {
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        }

        public int getCount() {
           // return myItems.size();
            return images.size();
        }

        public Bitmap getItem(int position) {
            return images.get(position);
            //return myItems.get(position);
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
           return position;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {

              final Bitmap image=(Bitmap)getItem(position);


            final ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.imageview2, null);


                holder.image = (ImageView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.imageView2);



                holder.Delete=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttonClose);

                convertView.setTag(holder);


            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();



            }




            BitmapFactory.Options factoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

            int imageWidth = factoryOptions.inDensity=70;
            int imageHeight = factoryOptions.inDensity=65;

       Bitmap Scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(images.get(position), imageWidth, imageHeight, true);
            holder.image.setImageBitmap(Scaled);

            holder.image.setTag(position);

            String me=  holder.image.getTag().toString();
            holder.Delete.setTag(position);

            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
            //encode image
            final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> imageHashMap=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
            byte[] b = bytes.toByteArray();
             encodedImageString = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
            // StringImages.add(encodedImageString); 

            imageHashMap.putString(String.valueOf(image.getTag()), encodedImageString);



            holder.image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                    final Dialog imgDialog = new Dialog(view.getContext(),android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);

                  imgDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
                  imgDialog.setCancelable(false);
                  //   layout imageview2 is used because when i use simple imageview layout dialogue with imageview and closebutton,  
                  //   every taken image at instance will not be shown in dialogue.
                  imgDialog.setContentView(R.layout.imageview);
                  Button btnClose = (Button)imgDialog.findViewById(R.id.btnIvClose);
                  ImageView ivPreview = (ImageView)imgDialog.findViewById(R.id.image1);






                  ivPreview.setImageBitmap(images.get(position));

                  btnClose.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                      @Override
                      public void onClick(View arg0) {

                          imgDialog.dismiss();
                      }
                  });
                  imgDialog.show();




                       myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        listviewattachment.setSelection(myAdapter.getCount()+1 );



                }
            });



            holder.Delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    int tag = (Integer) view.getTag();
                    if (tag != (images.size() )) {
                        images.remove(tag);

                        Log.d("GCM", "Item removed from " + tag);
                        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                }
                    if(imageHashMap.contains(tag)) { 
                        imageHashMap.remove(tag); }


                }
            });


            return convertView;
        }

    }
```

Comment: as you are removing the tag from "images", also remove the same from StringImages.

Comment: @Darah Shah can u please give me a little code ..how to remove it..please help me

Comment: **StringImages.add(encodedImageString);** this looks like a list, if i am not wrong, but since the string is encoded and coverted to bytes you will not be able to track the string belongs to which image. I suggest you use a hashmap<String, String> Where the key would be the tag that you use to remove the image. and against each tag you would have the encoded string.

Comment: Once that is done, when you remove the image from **images** list check if the hashmap contains the tag, if yes, remove the same from the hashmap. Write a function to get all the strings at the end and send them to the server. i hope that helps.

Comment: i have place code before return Convertview.In holder.delete on click i also added images.remove(position) now i am getting 15 false images on the server side on selecting just 1 images

Comment: please tell me how i track image tag using hash map....can u give me a little line of code..please

Comment: In this code: **@Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    int tag = (Integer) view.getTag();
                    if (tag != (images.size() )) {
                        images.remove(tag);

                        Log.d("GCM", "Item removed from " + tag);
                        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



                }** you are only removing the image from the images variable. there is nothing done to the encoded strings .

Comment: please waiting for your reply..i have spent whole night to sort out this..please help

Comment: encodedImageString  is this a string ?? and remove the array list declaration from the getview method.

Answer (score 0):

For an example, using hashmap look at this:

```
Bitmap Scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(images.get(position), imageWidth,imageHeight,true);
holder.image.setImageBitmap(Scaled);
holder.image.setTag(position);
holder.Delete.setTag(position);
Bitmap image=(Bitmap)getItem(position);
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
//encode image
byte[] b = bytes.toByteArray();
encodedImageString = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

StringImages.add(encodedImageString) -----> Instead of this line, use a hashmap like this

```
imageHashMap.put(String.valueOf(image.getTag()), encodedImageString);
```

and in the delete.onclicklistener code as you are removing image from images, like images.remove(image),

add these lines

```
if(imageHashMap.contains(image.getTag())) {
    imageHashMap.remove(image.getTag());
}
```

I hope this helps.
**PS: declare the hashmap in the constructor before you use it, else you might get a null pointer exception**

Comment: image.getTag is not defined...to create it's method..what should be it's return value?

Comment: holder.image.getTag() ??

Comment: also when getting the tag, convert it to integer, and then to string.

Comment: bro i have added updated code in original question according to your answer..i am getting redline under getTag();

Comment: holder.image.getTag is also not working ..it is casting hashMAp

Comment: change this **String.valueOf(image.getTag())** to String.valueOf((Integer)holder.image.getTag())

Comment: and change this **if(imageHashMap.contains(image.getTag())) {
                        imageHashMap.remove(image.getTag());
                    }** to **if(imageHashMap.contains(tag)) {
                        imageHashMap.remove(tag);
                    }**

Comment: also tried this   String me=  holder.image.getTag().toString();..it is again casting HashMap to Bundle and giving error

Comment: if you can manage to do this, holder.image.setTag(position); i am sure you can manage to get the tag also

Comment: issue is resolve in holder.delete but in  imageHashMap.putString(String.valueOf(image.getTag()), encodedImageString);  i am still getting error on getTag();

Comment: change this image.getTag() to holder.image.getTag()

Comment: imageHashMap.putString(String.valueOf(image.getTag()), encodedImageString); i am still getting error on getTag();

Comment: now after doing this  imageHashMap.putString(String.valueOf(holder.image.getTag()), encodedImageString);  , red line appears under putString, saying cast it to Bundle after casting it adds (Bundle)imageHashMap.putString(String.valueOf(holder.image.getTag()), encodedImageString); but not removing error

Comment: alright do one thing, remove the holder.image.getTag(), since you are using the position, simply pass the position, like this String.valueOf(position)

Comment: you can see my HashMap declaration   ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> imageHashMap=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

Comment: why do you need an array list ?? simply use HashMap<String, String> without the arraylist

Comment: declaration corrected    imageHashMap.putString(String.valueOf(position), encodedImageString);..again that cast to Bundle error

Comment: i have done 2 things  String me=  holder.image.getTag().toString();   and   imageHashMap.put(  me, encodedImageString);...error removed...i did it correct??

Comment: i am really sorry, instead of putString use the put method and it will solve the issue, yes correct, thats correct

Comment: i was concatenating imageStringArray previously using ToString function like imageStringArray.add(encodedimagestring) String imagesToServer=imageStringArray.ToString..then i passed imagesToServer to server...how can i concatenate hashMap putted strings

Comment: this was a line nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param6", imagesToServer));  now please tell how do i get imagesToServer according to new logic

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15022149/retrieving-hashmap-values-in-java?answertab=votes#tab-top, refer to this, instead of printing the values one by one, add them to a list or array.

Comment: byte[] b = bytes.toByteArray();
              encodedImageString = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
             // StringImages.add(encodedImageString); 
             
             imageHashMap.put(  me, encodedImageString);
          
             for(Entry<String, String> entry : imageHashMap.entrySet()) {
                 String key = entry.getKey();
                  value = entry.getValue();
                  StringImages.add(value);
             }
i have tried this now i am gettng 1MB of large images..i should recieve only 1

Comment: just check if the hashmap contains repeated values by debugging if so, add a condition that checks if the hashmap contains the key then in that case don't do anything else put the value into the hashmap. Are you trying to say that only one image is expected ?

Comment: actually what my code do is take image from camera and send to server..but according to our new logic when i take 1 image from camera , it gives me 3.4 MB size of large images

Comment: yes there was repeated values now i tried this  for(Entry<String, String> entry : imageHashMap.entrySet()) {
                 String key = entry.getKey();
                 if (imageHashMap.containsKey(key)){
                  
                  
                 }
                 else
                 
                 {  value = entry.getValue();
                  StringImages.add(value);}
             }
and it's showing now empty string

Comment: actually this is my start of career in my professional life...i am learning things...if it's annoying..really sorry

Comment: check for repeated values when add the encoded string into the hashmap itslf, not while receiving the list of strings.

Comment: thanks issue resolve of repeated image..but delete function is not working..am i doing any mistake in    holder.Delete.setOnClickListener

                 public void onClick(View view) {
                     int tag = (Integer) view.getTag();
                     if (tag != (images.size() )) {
                         images.remove(tag); 
                         myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();} 
                     if(imageHashMap.containsValue(tag)) { 
                      imageHashMap.remove(tag); }
                     myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39048/discussion-between-dhara-shah-and-user2768215)